# Smooth circular data - Matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I am currently doing some image segmentation on a bone qCT picture, see for instance images below.

[image]

I am trying to find the different borders in the picture for instance the outer border separating the bone to the noisy background. In this analysis I am getting a list of points (vec(1,:) containing x values and vex(2,:) containing the y values) in random order.

To get them into order I am using using a block of code which effectively takes the first point vec(1,1),vec(1,2) and then finds the closest point among the rest of the points in the vector. And then repeats.

Now my problem is that I want to smooth the data but how do I do that as the points lie in a circular formation? (I do have the Curve Fitting Toolbox)

Comment: can you upload an example of `vec` and the ordering of the points you get from your procedure?

Comment: For circular curves, you can fit a polynom `x(t)` and another for `y(t)` where `t` ranges over all your data points.

Comment: You can find an example of one of my vectors here: http://imada.sdu.dk/~nmatt11/files/  It is the one called O.mat and it contains a vector O.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a smoothing procedure, but a way to simplify your data would be to compute the boundary of the convex hull of the data.

```
K = convhull(O(1,:), O(2,:));
plot(O(1,K), O(2,K));
```

You could also consider using [alpha shapes](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28851-alpha-shapes) if you want more control.